# Multiple Salts to protect passwords

Tags: security, hash, passwords, salt

If you use a salt before hashing a password - it will make the hash more secure. It makes sense, because rainbow table attacks become much more difficult (impossible?).

What if you use multiple salts? For example - you check if the day is Monday, or the Month, the hour, etc (or some combination). Then you have a database which stores the fields: (userid, hash1, hash2, hash3...).

Would this make the information any more (or less) secure?

Example:

1) User registers with password 'PASS'.
2) System (php in this example) stores values (md5($password.$this_day)) for each day (7 passwords). into table password, column hash_monday, hash_tuesday etc.
3) user logs in, and script checks password where 'hash_'.$this_day matches what is entered.

Comment: Rainbow table attacks become more difficult, hashing doesn't save you from dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your system will be no more secure - you end up with several single salt databases instead of one. In principle it may be even less secure, since you helpfully provide the attacker with 7 hashes to the same string to choose from and he only needs to guess one. These multiple hashes of the same plaintext may also lead to implications to cryptographic strength of the encryption used for passwords (not sure on that one and it will depend on the algorithm used).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should have a look at this small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt). There are several things wrong with your approach.

1. A salt does not protect against a dictionary attack. It protects against rainbow-tables if correctly used.
2. Use a unique salt for each password. The salt should be a random value, not derrived from known information. It has to be stored with the password.
3. Do **not use MD5** for hashing passwords. Md5 is considered broken, and it is ways too fast to hash passwords. With an off-the-shelf GPU, you are able to calculate 8 Giga MD5-hashes per second ([in 2012](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance)). That makes it possible to brute-force a whole english dictionary with about 500000 words, in less than 0.1 milliseconds!
4. Use **Bcrypt** for hashing passwords. It is recommended to use a well established library like [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), and if you want to understand how it can be implemented, you can read the article above.

If you want to add a secret to your hash function (like a hidden key, or a hidden function), you can add a **pepper** to the password. The pepper should **not** be stored in the database, and should remain secret. The pepper can protect against dictionary attacks, as long as the attacker has only access to your password-hashes (SQL-Injection), but not to the server with the secret.

Comment: I am still not sold on the pepper saving you from dictionary attacks

Comment: @Woot4Moo - You are right so far, that it protects only from certain kind of attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe multiple hashes are going to help you in this scenario, primarily because when someone compromises your database they will notice that you have 7 different salts to go against and may make an educated guess that they are based on days of the week.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with MD5, as so many people like to jump on that bandwagon.  The types of people that say MD5 is a broken hash have a fundamental misunderstanding between a hash function and a cryptographic hash function, I would recommend ignoring them.  In the event you need a cryptographic hash function, use SHA-2 (or something from that family or greater).

You will need to salt the user input, as you know, a random value is generally recommended,but it can also be a value you store in a separate application space (outside of the database), you just have to protect that information as well.    I highly recommend making the password hashing function take several thousand iterations for any input. As this will slow down the automated process of matching hashes on the database.

If your users use easy to guess passwords, dictionary attacks will beat you every day, cant protect against stupidity.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with hash versus cryptographic hash, for storing passwords you need a cryptographic hash. A hash is considered broken, if there is a known way to get a collision, that is faster than brute-forcing. And of course MD5 is much too fast, as you correctly pointed out. The salt is not a secret, there is no need to hide it, if you want to add a secret, you add a pepper. I would not mix salt and pepper up, since they have a different purpose. The pepper **can** protect against weak passwords, in some cases (SQL-Injection).

Comment: @martinstoeckli do you have a research paper that states a pepper protects against weak passwords?  Based on my understanding of a pepper that makes zero sense.  There are two categories of hashes, normal hashes (MD5) and cryptographic hashes (SHA).  There is nothing wrong with MD5, and the "ease" of collision is not as high as the doom sayers make it out to be.  I would recommend a crypto hash in the event I am storing passwords, but fundamentally MD5 is fine and all the hashing in the world won't save you from poor passwords.

Comment: A pepper only protects from dictionary attacks, if the attacker does **not** have control over the server (and therefore the code with the secret). This is typically the case if the attacker was successful with SQLInjection. You add the pepper to the (weak) passwort, so instead of "12345" you are actually hashing "12345ai8-9?uz3dWe" and that you will find in no dictionary.

Comment: By the way, what you suggested with iterating, is solved with a key derivation function, see **PBKDF2**. With PBKDF2 even an MD5 could be used, but is not recommended.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I was under the impression that the input supplied to the pepper will always be the same (assuming hash + salt) gets supplied to the pepper function.  The output will always be the same, I guess I am missing something critical here.

Comment: Like the salt, the pepper is just a combination of random characters, the same pepper can be used for all passwords. It will be combined with the password, before calculating the hash, therefore a weak password becomes strong `password+pepper`. If you now have a dictionary but don't know the pepper, the words in the dictionary are useless. The same applies to a pepper function, it will scramble up the weak password in a secret way, and then you calculate the hash of this scrambled password.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the pepper is not a replacement for the salt, it is just a possible addition.